# Is my solution of $\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( \frac{\cos (x^2+y)}{1-x^2y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{x^4+y^2}}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Is this solution correct?

If not, why?

Alternative (especially less wordy) proofs are also welcome.

$$\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( \frac{\cos (x^2+y)}{1-x^2y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{x^4+y^2}}$$
$$y=x^2$$
$$\lim_{(x, x^2)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\left( \frac{\cos (2x^2)}{1-x^4}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2x^4}}$$
$$x^2=a$$
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\cos (2a)}{1-a^2}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2a^2}}$$
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} e^{\ln \left( \frac{\cos (2a)}{1-a^2}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2a^2}}}$$
Zooming in on the power:
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} {\ln \left( \frac{\cos (2a)}{1-a^2}\right) {\frac{1}{2a^2}}}.$$
In the neighborhood of $0$, $\cos(2a)$ is barely distinguishable from $1$:
$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln\frac{1}{1-a^2}}{2a^2} = \langle \frac{0}{0} \rangle,$$

so L'Hôpital:

$$ \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{-(-2a)}{(1-a^2)^2}(1-a^2)}{4a} = \frac{1}{2} .$$

The answer: $\sqrt{e}.$

Comment: @PeterForeman  $y=e^x$ is not a path through the origin.

Comment: @zhw. Oh yeah oops. I don't completely agree with you about the limit not existing though because of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+as+%28x%2Cy%29+to+%280%2C0%29+of+%28cos%28x%5E2%2By%29%2F%281-x%5E2y%29%29%5E%281%2F%28x%5E4%2By%5E2%29%29)

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, looks like a made an error. Thanks, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have approached this by looking at one curve, namely $y=x^2.$ And that curve should have yielded the limit $e^{-1/2}.$ So there's that mistake. The bigger mistake is: One curve is never enough.

We can write

$$\tag 1 \cos (x^2+y) = 1-\frac{(x^2+y)^2}{2} +o(x^4+y^2)$$

and

$$\tag 2 \frac{1}{1-x^2y} = 1 + x^2y + o(x^4+y^2).$$

The product of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is then

$$\tag 3 1-\frac{x^4+y^2}{2}+ o(x^4+y^2).$$

Rasing $(3)$ to the power $\dfrac{1}{x^4+y^2}$ and taking the limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ shows the desired limit is $e^{-1/2}.$

**Note** This is edited from the original, which contained a mistake that Peter Foreman pointed out to me.